# Removing an elasticsearch cluster default setting dynamically

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to remove a default cluster setting. This is what I tried.

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/_cluster/settings  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d' 
{
  "transient": {
      "cluster.some_setting_has_default_value_only": null
    }
}
'
```

However, this does not work and I can still see the setting in `localhost:9200/_cluster/settings?pretty&flat_settings&include_defaults`.

On debugging I found that since this setting does not exist in the `transient` settings, it does not bother removing this setting and therefore the default value is still applied. I verified the same with `persistent` key too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot remove a default setting. You can only override it either in the `transient` section (will not survive restart) or in the `persistent` section (will survive restart).

Comment: Thanks! I verified this myself on a cluster. However, this is not present in any of the documentation so wanted to know if I'm missing something